# Sequelize: Insert failed to foreignKey column

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm trying to insert data to my table with foreign keys from another table. The relationship is already successfully created. But when I try to insert data to the table, it always input null, and I already handle it with add allowNull: false. But still don't know how to input the value into the foreign key value inside table column.

This is my Product model:

```
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      description: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: true
      },
      price: {
        type: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          isNumeric: {
            args: true,
            msg: 'Wrong price format'
          }
        }
      },
      image: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
      }
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      paranoid: true,
      modelName: 'product'
    }
  );
```

and this is my category model:

```
category.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      image: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
      }
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      paranoid: true,
      modelName: 'category'
    }
  );
```

and this is relationship between them

```
category.hasMany(product, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'categoryId',
    allowNull: false
  },
  onDelete: 'CASCADE'
});
product.belongsTo(category, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'categoryId',
    allowNull: false
  },
  onDelete: 'CASCADE'
});
```

and on inserting code using express, this is the code:

```
const product = {
    name,
    description,
    price,
    image,
    businessCompanyId,
    categoryId
  };

await Product.create(product);
```

Any help will be great, thank you!

Comment: What error do you get after running the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a field of `categoryId` in Product model like this:-

```
categoryId: {
  type: DataTypes.UUID,
  allowNull: false,
  references: {
    model: "category",
    key: "id"
  }
},
```

I have not proper understanding of `businessCompanyId` but hope this will help you!

Comment: Hi, now I can insert to categoryId column inside product table. But when I try to findAll and join with category I got error is not associated to

```
Product.findAll({
    include: [Category]
  })
```

error: category is not associated to the product!

Do u have any idea about this?